# Bash script to run python script in python environment runs on ubuntu command line but not in crontab

Tags: python, linux, bash, cron

I have this crontab to run the bash script predictions.sh at a certain time every day. The script does not run in the crontab, but it runs on the ubuntu command line. I am using AWS Ubuntu 16.04.5.

```
#!/bin/sh -x
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=~/bin:~/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
51 14 * * * ./predictions.sh
```

The bash script itself runs a python file after activating a python environment 'dateprep':

```
source dataprep/bin/activate
cd dataprep
python datafiles.py
```

Would any one know how to get the crontab to work? Thank you

Comment: The `.` is the current directory - crontab is not running from where you expect. Put only full paths in the crontab.

Comment: The shebang line is not even wrong; the file contains a `cron` schedule, not a shell script.

Comment: Your Python script should not typically be inside the virtual environment; the virtual environment should contain things which aren't yours.